# How double pointer really behaves this way?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, double-pointer

Is not that true that **double pointer store address of a pointer only**?
How it can then store an integer address?

```
{
    int **ptr,a;
    a = 10;
    ptr = &a; 

    printf("value of a = %d\n",*ptr);  //why it works?
    printf("value of a = %d\n",**ptr); //why it doesnt work?

}
```

Comment: First of all, the correct format specifier to print a pointer (really a `void *`, typecast is actually needed to be fully correct) is `"%p"`.

Comment: The compiler will also already warn you that something is probably wrong: `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] ptr = &a;`

Comment: And if you switch from C99 to C++ this "warning only" situation has changed: `error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' in assignment`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for your problem, because you make `ptr` point to `&a`, then doing `*ptr` will lead to the same result as doing `*(&a)` which gives you the value of where `&a` is pointing, which is the value of `a`. It's semantically incorrect though, and could lead to other problems if the size of `int *` (which is what `*ptr` really is) is different from the size of `int` (which is what `a` is).

When you do `**ptr` you treat the value of `a` as a pointer, and dereference it. Since `10` is unlikely to be a valid pointer on a modern PC you will get *undefined behavior*.

---

You say "double pointer store address of a pointer", and that's correct. A pointer to a pointer can store an address (pointer) of a pointer. But `&a` is not an address of a pointer, it's the address of the non-pointer variable `a`.

For a "double pointer" (pointer to pointer really) to work, you need something like

```
int a = 10;
int *ptr = &a;  // Make ptr point to the variable a
int **ptrptr = &ptr;  // Make ptrptr point to the variable ptr
```

After this, `*ptrptr == ptr`, and `**ptrptr == *ptr` and `**ptrptr == a`.

Somewhat graphically the above could be seen something like

```
+--------+     +-----+     +---+
| ptrptr | --> | ptr | --> | a |
+--------+     +-----+     +---+
```

Comment: After `ptr = &a;`, `*ptr` is not the same as `*(&a)`. Presuming the compiler accepts it, it is `* (int **) &a`, for which the behavior is not defined by the C standard, and, even if the compiler does support aliasing, it would have problems if `int` and `int *` are different sizes. It’s okay to explain to people what caused the behavior they observed, even if that behavior is not defined by the C standard (because it promotes understanding of how computers work), but it is not good to make false statements about language semantics.

Comment: Thank you i knew how to work with pointer but couldnt understand really how this work just exact the same thought i had when i went to rest after asking this question.

Answer (score -1):

> Is not that true that double pointer store address of a pointer only?

No. A pointer of any type **can store** address of anything. But ideally programmer should make sure that address of valid type is stored in it.

By doing    `ptr = &a;` you are storing address of an integer in a double pointer variable.

```
printf("value of a = %d\n",*ptr);  //why it works?
```

`*ptr` will return value at address stored by `ptr`. Since address stored is of an integer variable, it returns the integer value. But note that, the returned value will have address type since ptr is a double pointer. However, in `printf()`, you are using `%d` to print the value. So pointer type value returned by `*ptr` will be typecasted to integer and get printed. So you get proper output.

```
printf("value of a = %d\n",**ptr); //why it doesnt work?
```

This is not working because it is equivalent to `(*(*ptr))`. So you are trying to read integer value stored at address 10. I think either it is not a valid address on your machine or your program doesn't have permission to read that address.

PS: You must be getting compiler warnings. They give some hints.

Comment: The first print only works by accident. If the size of a pointer is not same as size of an integer, it will fail. Using wrong format specifier is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes. I missed that point. But usually sizeof(int) <= sizeof(void*) I believe. So it works in most of the cases.

Comment: It is not true that “A pointer of any type can store the address of anything.” Pointers to incompatible types are generally incompatible, per the C standard. For example, the behavior of converting a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type with stricter alignment is undefined if the operand does not have the required alignment.

Comment: Re “`*ptr` will return value at address stored by ptr. Since address stored is of an integer variable, it returns the integer value.”: These are not correct statements of C semantics. First, the behavior of accessing an `int` through an `int *` is not defined by the C standard. If it does execute, it may fetch the bytes that represent the `int` and interpret them as a pointer—**not** as an integer value—and hence may have a value different from the integer. (Today’s ubiquitous flat address spaces lead people to think pointers are simply numbers that are addresses, but this is not always so.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't get. Can you give an example or a link? As per my understanding, pointer variable is just a placeholder for address. It does not matter address of which type you are storing in it. But during dereferencing, you may face issues if they are incompatible.

Comment: Re “However, in printf(), you are using %d to print the value. So pointer type value returned by *ptr will be typecasted to integer and get printed.”: No, a `printf` argument corresponding to a `%d` specification is not “typecasted” to integer. The behavior of passing an argument with `int *` type in a position corresponding to a `%d` specification is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @MayurK: No, a pointer is not just a placeholder for an address. A pointer has a value and a type. A type of `int *` is different from a type of `char *`. The C standard has rules about how pointers behave, and those rules involve the specific type of the pointer. For example, C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 says “A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks! It is really some useful information. :)